# I can't send a parameter through graphql query

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo

i'm reciving the error `Variable "$id" of required type "String!" was not provided.`  Someone knows why?

**In my backend (node-mongo-graphql)**

Mutation:

```
type Mutation {
    deleteAmbiente(_id: String!): Ambiente
}
```

Resolver:

```
async deleteAmbiente(_,_id, context) {
        console.log("hi there!", _id)
}
```

**In my front-end (vue + apollo)**

```
async deleteAmbiente() {
  try {
    let id = this.item._id
   const res =  await apolloClient.mutate({
      mutation: ELIMINAR_AMBIENTE,
      variables: id, // id has a value, if i send "hello" from here, it doesn't work either
    });
  console.log(res)
  } catch (err) {
    err;
  }
},

export const ELIMINAR_AMBIENTE = gql`
mutation deleteAmbiente(
    $id: String!
){
  deleteAmbiente(_id:$id){
    nombre
  }
}
`
```

Comment: imagine that you need to send two values/variables - how?

Comment: i just need send one variable, a string (the id of the ``ambiente``)

Comment: @xadm
if i would need to send more than one var i would create a custom input type

Comment: it's not required, optimization rather

Comment: eh, `variables` is/should be an object, with `id` prop